# Phpmailer and contact form, success message, but no result

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer, contacts

Here my php code for contact form using PhpMailer.

```
<?php 
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    include_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
    include_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";
    include_once "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        echo $subject . "<br/>";
        echo $email . "<br/>";
        echo $message . "<br/>";
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $mail->addAddress('example@gmail.com');
        $mail->setFrom($email);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Body = $message;

        if ($mail->send())
            echo "Your email has been sent, thank you!";
        else
            echo "Please try again!";

    }
?>
```

It shows "Your email has been sent, thank you", but does not send anyting.
How can solve it?

Comment: Welcome! Check the PHP Error log file. To find it, look for the `error_log` parameter in your `php.ini` file. This file probably contains error information that will help you solve your problem.

Comment: You're not using SMTP (so including that class is unnecessary), but it also means that a successful run of this script may not succeed in delivering the message - you will need to look in your local *mail* server's log file, usually somewhere like `/var/log/mail.log`

Comment: Mail is being sent to **example@gmail.com** address, change it to your email address where you can receive submitted mail.